# Avoiding raw type for a collection with different types

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

Im having the following situation:

I used the `command` pattern like the following:

```
public interface Command<T extends EObject>
{
 void runCommand(T classToMap, String fieldForMapping);
}
```

As someone might notice, I am working with the `Eclipse Modelling Framework` but that doesnt matter for this question.

In another class I have a HashMap as a mappingDirectory, the key returns another Map.

```
private final static HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Command>> mappingDirectory = new HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Command>>();
```

To this mappingDirectory I add various maps looking like this:

```
private final static LinkedHashMap<String, Command> classOneMappings = new LinkedHashMap<String, Command>();
private final static LinkedHashMap<String, Command> classTwoMappings = new LinkedHashMap<String, Command>();
```

... and so on. These maps get filled with keys and the mentioned command interface:

```
classOneMappings.put("someKey", new Command<ClassOne>()
  {
     @Override
     public void runCommand(ClassOne classToMap, String fieldForMapping)
     {
        classToMap.setName(fieldForMapping);
     };
  });
```

In the end I've got many implemented command interfaces with different types. So how can I avoid the raw type of just using `Command` for the `mappingDirectory` and the contained maps?

I thought it would be possible to get this working like this:

```
HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Command<? extends EObject>>> mappingDirectory = new HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Command<? extends EObject>>>();
```

and declaring the other maps with their specific types which are **all** `EObjects`:

```
private final static LinkedHashMap<String, Command<ClassOne>> classOneMappings = new LinkedHashMap<String, Command<ClassOne>>();
```

but sadly putting them into the `mappingDirectory` will result into a compilation error.

Maybe I am just overlooking something, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note 1: Generics are invariant! There are lots of articles in the web that discuss that topic.

Note 2: You are using generics in two "layers" of your data structure. That will sometimes be confusing.

Your problem is the following: You are creating subtypes of the Command type with your anonymous class declarations. But you limit the value type in the inner map declaration of your directory to Command only. With the following variation you also allow subtypes:

```
Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Command<?>>> mappingDirectory = ...
```

Now you can (and should) declare

```
Map<String, Command<ClassOne>> classOneMappings = ...
```

and put it into the directory:

```
mappingDirectory.put("...", classOneMappings);
```

(Note that I used only the interface type Map.)

---

EDIT:

For the following example, I will use the classes `Number`, `Integer`, and `Double` (all in package `java.lang`). They are doing their job just fine here. I will also use Java 7 to have the nice type inference when instantiating generics.

I'll start with the `Command` interface:

```
interface Command<T extends Number> {
    void run(T number, String field);
}
```

With that you are able to do the following:

```
class NestedGenerics {
    private static final Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Command>> DIRECTORY = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Command<Integer>> integerMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Command<Double>> doubleMap = new HashMap<>();

        integerMap.put("integer_command", new Command<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void run(Integer number, String field) {
                System.out.println(field + ": " + number);
            }
        });
        doubleMap.put("double_command", new Command<Double>() {
            @Override
            public void run(Double number, String field) {
                System.out.println(field + ": " + number);
            }
        });

        DIRECTORY.put("integers", integerMap);
        DIRECTORY.put("doubles", doubleMap);

        DIRECTORY.get("integers").get("integer_command").run(Integer.valueOf(42), "integer field");
        DIRECTORY.get("doubles").get("double_command").run(Double.valueOf(42.0), "double field");
    }
}
```

A little disadvantage here is, that you use the `Command` type as a raw type in the directory's declaration. But as you are putting various maps with various `Command` subtypes into this directory, the `Command` class' bound to `Number` (remind: `T extends Number`) might be enough for the usage.

This example compiles and runs just fine. Its output is:

> integer field: 42
>
> double field: 42.0

Comment: Thanks for your time :) This sadly results into the same problem as Rohits suggestion: A compile error complaining that I cant invoke the runCommand method with an EObject. For more details please look below, the first comment to Rohits suggestion.

Comment: Ok, the only out in this case is to declare the variable `mappingDirectory` as `Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Command>>`. I'll edit my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Alright, that's a lot better then it was before. I guess this cant be enchanced any further without changing the structure itself. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between outer-most level wildcards, and the nested wildcards is that, the nested wildcards don't capture.

Consider the below 2 declarations:

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();     // 1
List<List<? extends Number>> list2 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();   // 2

List<List<? extends Number>> list3 = new ArrayList<List<? extends Number>>();// 3
```

Although the first declaration is perfectly valid, as we know that `List<? extends Number>` can capture `ArrayList<Integer>`, the second declaration is not valid. A `List<List<? extends Number>>`, doesn't capture `ArrayList<List<Integer>>`. You have to use only the third declaration.

So, applying the same logic to your maps, if you have declared a `Map` like this:

```
private static HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Command<? extends EObject>>> mappingDirectory = 
        new HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Command<? extends EObject>>>();
```

You can only add to them a `Map` like these:

```
private static LinkedHashMap<String, Command<? extends EObject>> classOneMappings = 
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Command<? extends EObject>>();
private static LinkedHashMap<String, Command<? extends EObject>> classTwoMappings = 
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Command<? extends EObject>>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Rohit. I also tried it like this, but trying to call a method: `mappingDirectory.get(0).runCommand(eObject, fields[i]);` results into following compilation error: `The method runCommand(capture#69-of ? extends EObject, String) in the type Command<capture#69-of ? extends EObject> is not applicable for the arguments (EObject, String)`. This error pretty confuses me...

Comment: @Ben How does your `runCommand` method look like. Show me the code, where you are populating the inner maps.

Comment: The code should be above in my answer, the part `classOneMappings.put("someKey", new Command<ClassOne>()...` or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, the problem is, while fetching value from map, you will get back - `Command<? extends EObject>`, and for that you can't just pass `ClassOne` instance to `runCommand`. In fact, you can only pass `null` to it. It's the same issue as, you can't add anything to a `List<? extends Number>`, except `null`.

Comment: That sucks. ;) So its valid to say that this counts to the unavoidable situations of using raw types? Thanks for the clarification anyway...

Comment: @Ben Well, any workaround for this would be an ugly one. It would be better, if you could modify your structure a bit. Having 3 levels of nested wildcard, anyways starts to go wierd very soon.